# What is the name of this monoid law?

Tags: haskell

In the documentation for `Data.Monoid`, it states the following laws should be satisfied:

```
mappend mempty x = x
mappend x mempty = x
mappend x (mappend y z) = mappend (mappend x y) z
mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
```

My understanding of these is that the first 2 are identity, and the third is associativity.

But what is the law in the fourth line? Identity again, but for `mconcat`?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a name for this since it doesn't really have much to do with monoids. That “law” is merely the _definition of `mconcat`_. A `Monoid` instance may override this for better performance, but it should always have the semantics of the reference implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematically, the definition of a monoid requires the existence of something like `mempty` and something like `mappend`, satisfying the first three laws: left and right identity, and associativity.

The `mconcat` method has been added to the class to reflect the fact that accumulation in a list is often what one does with monoids. The fourth law is the *executable specification* of `mconcat`: indeed, that very law is the line of code which gives the default implementation of `mconcat`. Making `mconcat` a member of the class means that, per `Monoid` instance, you are free to give `mconcat` a more efficient implementation, just as long as it agrees with the default.

It's not clear to me that making `mconcat` reimplementable in this way is a particularly big win. I'd tend to avoid `mconcat` in favour of (the confusingly named) `fold`.

Comment: Right, although `fold` does have the disadvantage that the monoid gets no say in the fold association order that's chosen. And while that must not matter semantically, it certainly can have a significant impact on strictness/performance (the classic example being of course: it would be very inefficient if we had `mconcat = foldl' mappend mempty` for lists).

Comment: Yes. I'd prefer the name "crush", as it happens. The trouble is that "fold" has two meanings which coincide only in `foldr`. Meanwhile, it would indeed be good to be able to indicate whether, for a given monoid, either bias in association is to be preferred. It's not obvious that the implementation of `mconcat` is the best way to signal that.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `mconcat` is not to provide any more information about the monoid; it is an implementation detail. It is a convenience function, but one that might be implemented more efficiently than its default definition. When infinite lists are considered, "more efficient" can mean "possible".

Consider the `Product` monoid. The following never terminates, using the default definition of `mconcat`:

```
mconcat (map Product [0..])
```

even though it should be obvious that *any* list of integers containing 0 should produce 0. However, if you were to redefine the function as

```
mconcat = foldr (\acc v -> if acc == Product 0 then Product 0 else mappend acc v) empty
```

Then the product of an infinite list containing at least one zero would still terminate. (Of course, an infinite list of of non-zero values would still never terminate, but this `mconcat` is still more efficient for large lists that contain an "early" zero.)